# Delete does not recognise pointer allocation from List

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

When I try to call delete on pointers to a `struct Vertex` (allocated with `Vertex * v = new Vertex`, then successfully used and stored in an `std::list` in my class destructor, I get this runtime error:

```
graphtake3(12325,0x100082000) malloc: *** error for object 0x100200340: pointer being freed was not allocated
***
```

The pointers are definitely being allocated, as the application runs fine, and everything appears as it should in a stack trace, but for some reason, `delete` can't seem to deallocated them. What's happening here, and why doesn't delete work?

Here is the relevant abbreviated code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Color {BLACK, GREY, WHITE};

struct Vertex {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    Color color;

    Vertex();
    Vertex(std::string name);

    ~Vertex();

};
class Graph {
    std::vector<std::list<Vertex *>> adjList;

public:
    Graph();
    Graph (int nodeCount);

    ~Graph();

    int newVertex();
    int newVertex(std::string name);
    void newUnDirectedEdge(int v1, int v2);
    void newDirectedEdge(int v1, int v2);
    std::list<Vertex*> getConnections(int v);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g);



};
```

and

```
#include "Graph.hpp"

Vertex::Vertex() {
    color = WHITE;
}

Vertex::Vertex(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
    color = WHITE;
}

Vertex::~Vertex() {

}

Graph::Graph() {

}

Graph::Graph(int nodeCount) {
    adjList.reserve(nodeCount);
}

Graph::~Graph(){
    for (int i = 0; i<adjList.size(); i++) {

        for (std::list<Vertex*>::iterator iterator = adjList[i].begin(), end = adjList[i].end(); iterator !=end; iterator++) {
            delete (*iterator); //fails
        }
    }
}

int Graph::newVertex() {
    Vertex * v = new Vertex();
    adjList.push_back(std::list<Vertex *>(1, v));
    v->id= (int)adjList.size()-1;
    return v->id;
}

int Graph::newVertex(std::string name) {
    Vertex * v = new Vertex();
    adjList.push_back(std::list<Vertex *>(1, v));
    v->id= (int)adjList.size()-1;
    v->name= name;
    return v->id;
}

void Graph::newUnDirectedEdge(int v1, int v2) {
    newDirectedEdge(v1, v2);
    newDirectedEdge(v2, v1);
}

void Graph::newDirectedEdge(int v1, int v2) {
    Vertex * vertex2 = adjList[v2].front();
    adjList[v1].push_back(vertex2);

}
std::list<Vertex*> Graph::getConnections(int v) {
    return adjList[v];
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g) {
    for (int i = 0; i<g.adjList.size(); i++) {
        for (std::list<Vertex*>::const_iterator iterator = g.adjList[i].begin(), end = g.adjList[i].end(); iterator !=end; iterator++) {
            os << (*iterator)->id << " (" << (*iterator)->name << ") ";
        }
        os << '\n';
    }

    return os;
}
```

with main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.hpp"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Graph graph(5);

    int v1 = graph.newVertex("Paris");
    int v2 = graph.newVertex("London");
    int v3 = graph.newVertex("Lyon");
    int v4 = graph.newVertex("Nice");
    int v5 = graph.newVertex("Marseille");
    int v6 = graph.newVertex("La Rochelle");
    int v7 = graph.newVertex("Toulon");

    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v2, v1);
    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v1, v3);
    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v1, v4);
    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v3, v4);
    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v5, v4);
    graph.newUnDirectedEdge(v7, v5);

    std::cout << graph;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal but **complete** demo that readers can try. This sounds like a rule-of-3 problem. But impossible to say for sure without the code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, I added a more complete implementation

Comment: Thanks for the update, Btw. add `Graph(const Graph&) = delete;` (assuming you're using C++11) to your `Graph` class decl. If your code compile starts puking in various places, you're *definitely* violating [rule-of-three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, I added my `main()`. I haven't yet implemented a copy constructor, so I am, but how does that stop delete from working in this case?

Comment: @TheInnerParty I just ran your code, in this case it wouldn't since `Graph` is never copied (think about what would happen if it were, and two `Graph` objects had two `std::list` that both contained the *same* pointers). Which, btw, is closely related to your real problem. Your adjacency lists can *share* pointers to the same Vertex objects. At least that's what it appears they do from what I see. As soon as you clear a list, every *other* list that holds a pointer to one or more vertices that was in the list-just-cleared are now dangling, and using them invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig ohh, I get it now. It deletes it the first time, and then the next time it encounters a pointer to the now deleted struct, it raises that error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minute you do this, you are set up for disaster:

```
void Graph::newDirectedEdge(int v1, int v2) {
    Vertex * vertex2 = adjList[v2].front();
    adjList[v1].push_back(vertex2);
}
```

The problem is that you have not distinguished who *owns* a pointer.  In this case, you have simply copied a pointer onto the list.  But when you come around to `~Graph`, you delete *all* pointers in the list.  Some of them were obtained by `new`, and some were copied by the above function.

So the error was right: the pointer was not allocated.  What happened is you already deleted it, and then you deleted a copy of it.

You need to rethink your design and consider pointer ownership.  Or you could use the sledge-hammer approach of converting everything to `std::shared_ptr`.  But I wouldn't actually recommend that.

A common approach for graphs is to store all your vertices (in a `std::vector`) and then connect in a separate structure as you have done.  Then in the destructor you just rip through the vector.  You could even take this as an opportunity learn how to use `std::unique_ptr`. =)

Comment: You're right, I hadn't realised that. Is this considered a good solution: When doing delete, check if the pointer is null, else call `delete` and set the pointer to null?

Comment: No, `delete` will have no affect on a null pointer.  The problem is that you have two copies of a pointer and you try to delete them both.  Deleting one does not magically change the value of the other one to null.

Comment: Setting the pointer to null would not save you from this error. The copied pointer still remains untouched and the delete will still fail.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it: just delete the first pointer in every list, like so: `for (int i = 0; i<adjList.size(); i++) {
  
  delete (adjList[i].front()); }` Now they're all going to be unique, and it'll go through every vertex

Comment: The new edited answer actually seems like a better way, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem occur in the newDirectedEdge function?
In the implement of it, it copy pointer and insert list again, then two pointers for one address in the list, delete first time is ok, and second time ... crash ...